# Unable to focus on a text field under Iframe through protractor

Tags: protractor, dynamics-crm

I am trying here the QuickView form of MS Dynamics CRM. The text fields are under IFrame. Through the below java script, it's accessible: fname

```
//enter fname value
browser.executeScript("window.onload = document.getElementById('NavBarGloablQuickCreate').contentWindow.document.getElementById('firstname_i').value = 'rupam'"); But only first name is selected, if we try to do for the rest fields, it's not working.  Hence, decided to do it through protractor code, 
// Swtich to iFrame
 browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id("NavBarGloablQuickCreate")));
// Setting anme in first name text field 
element(by.id('firstname_i')).sendKeys('Indra');
```

But here, it says element is not contactable.

Comment: share you GUI and html to get a better view on the problem

Comment: @Madhan : It's a intranet GUI, cannot be shared here. I can share the code for angular for the UI automation till now. Please let me know where to share, here, the line limitations are there.

Comment: update html in the question

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it but were missing the `.getWebElement()` from your switchTo line. This is required as per the [protractor documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.switchTo).

```
// Switch to iFrame
browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id("NavBarGloablQuickCreate")).getWebElement());
//set name
element(by.id('firstname_i')).sendKeys('Indra');
```

Can you try the below and let me know.

Comment: @user2637375 this borders on harassment. Do not spam the comments asking for help. Write a clear question.

Comment: @DublinDev : As I have stated that I am using the java script to focus the element. Example : browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id("NavBarGloablQuickCreate")).getWebElement());

browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('firstname_i').focus()");
browser.sleep('6000');
element(by.id('firstname_i')).sendKeys('Indra'); Still getting Error : Wbdriver EDrror : element not interactable
Stack:
  WebDriverError: element not intractable ....From: Task: WebElement.sendKeys()

Comment: @DublinDev : What I understand from doing various tricks/ tips, it's a issue of focus and we need to blink the cursor on the text field. Instead of .focus() through javascript (Which I have already tried), what are the other options available in Protractor ?

Comment: I haven't had to interact with an element of this nature so can only really make guesses but you could try using [actions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions) to either click or else move the mouse to a particular coordinates and then click. You'll find protractors methods of interacting with elements in that link but they do not offer much more than you are aware of. It may be worth submitting another question for this topic as it appears your issue is not related to the iframe any longer

Comment: @DublinDev : Ok, Thanks. Shall do.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue to work with Dynamics CRM Quick view forms.I am trying to set a values on different fields of Quick view forms using SendKeys().But the value is not showing and cursor is not moving from one control to anaother.I have tried to move TAB using protractor TAB values also.But it's not showing.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.